# Is there a way to do a SELF JOIN on on the same column?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, one-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

I currently have an inelegant solution that requires iterating through thousands of rows one at a time and I would like to know if it's possible to do this with a single SQL statement.

I have a database table called `history` that holds a record of all transactions on another database called `inventory`. Both databases share a column called `pKey` (the foreign key).

My Inventory database:

```
| ID | pKey | model | room | ip | active | ... |
```

My history database: **The pKey is the foreign key**

```
| ID | pKey | fieldName | oldValue | newValue |
```

In the history database there can be more than 20 transactions for a single pKey. I would like to find all rows in the history that have:

1. fieldName of A AND oldValue of B
2. fieldName of C AND oldValue of D
3. the same pKey.

I.e. say we find that we have a row in the history table with fieldName of A and old Value of B, the result will only be valid if the pKey associated with that row also turns up in the search for rows with a fieldName of C and oldValue of D.

After doing some research it seems that SELF JOIN would be a good bet, but I am getting errors since I'm trying to do an SELF JOIN on the same column. Here is my statement:

```
SELECT pKey FROM `history` INNER JOIN history ON history.pKey=history.pKey WHERE `fieldName` = 'ipAddress' AND `oldValue` LIKE '129.97%'
```

**EDIT:** I made a mistake writing my statement here; I only mean to select the pKey results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need to perform SELF-JOIN, you have to give an alias to the copy of your table being joined.

Please find the query below - here both sides were aliased:

```
SELECT 
    history_AB.pKey
FROM 
    history  AS  history_AB
    INNER JOIN history  AS  history_CD 
        ON history_AB.pKey = history_CD.pKey 
WHERE 
    (history_AB.fieldName = 'A' AND history_AB.oldValue LIKE 'B%')
    AND (history_CD.fieldName = 'C' AND history_CD.oldValue LIKE 'D%')
```

In the `WHERE` clause there are conditions you mentioned in your question:

> (...) say we find that we have a row in the history table with
>   fieldName of A and old Value of B, the result will only be valid if
>   the pKey associated with that row also turns up in the search for rows
>   with a fieldName of C and oldValue of D

I hope I understood the problem well and it might help you some way.

Comment: This is VERY close to what I want. Is it possible to select only the pKeys?

Comment: Hi. Yes no problem. I've updated my answer to your remarks. Regards :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to identify the two instances of history as separate elements.  Using your "ABCD" example instead of your statement:

```
SELECT * FROM history h1 
INNER JOIN history h2
ON h1.pKey=h2.pKey 
WHERE h1.fieldName = 'A' AND h1.oldValue = 'B' 
AND h2.fieldName = 'C' AND h2.oldValue = 'D'
```

Comment: TG and John beat me to it. :)

Comment: This was essentially what I was looking for. Thanks a lot, this is WAY more efficient than how I was doing it.

Comment: The second "oldvalue" should have the prefix "h2" instead of "h1".

Answer (score 1):

If you do a self-join then you generally need to assign table aliases in order to be able to refer unambiguously to *any* column of either table.  Thus, you probably want something like this:

```
SELECT
  histA.pKey AS pKey,
  histA.newValue AS newA,
  histC.newValue AS newC,
FROM
  history histA
  INNER JOIN history histC
    ON histA.pKey = histC.pKey
WHERE
  histA.fieldName = 'A'
  AND histA.oldValue = 'B'
  AND histC.fieldName = 'C'
  AND histC.oldValue = 'D'
```

Of course, you can write the selction list as you want, including just selecting `*`, but I recommend at least assigning column aliases to help you sort out which data come from which table.